# Selenium framework and test data in json

Tags: selenium, frameworks

I am just completed a test automation using with `selenium`. And I want to know about how to keep the test data separately in `json` format.

Can you please tell me how to write test data in the `page object pattern`.

Here I am using multiple packages. One is for locators identification, another is for page factory for initializing elements, and the other is package utilities for common values like get URL. I also have a test package for testing a login module.

What I don't know is where should I put the test data class ?

I want to keep the test data separately. Not scattering all over the script. Keep the test data in Json. And read it from there where ever it is necessary.

Still I'm getting confusing about where Should I put the `json format`

And also I am `selenium` code doesn't follow a framework. I did n't follow any frameworks. Anybody please tell me about frameworks ?

Frameworks are : `Data driven`, `keyword driven`, `hybrid` and `modular`. which framework is most people using , because and why ?

As a tester should have knowledge about all frameworks ?

I am following page `object design pattern`:

**Page object :**

```
package pageobjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class HomePage
{
    @FindBy(how= How.NAME, using = "username")
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using = "password")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id=\'login-container\']/form/div[3]/div/p/input[1]" )
    WebElement button;

    //enter  username
    public void  userLogin(String user, String pass)
    {
        username.sendKeys(user);
        password.sendKeys(pass);
        button.click();
    }

}
```

**Steps:**

```
package steps;  
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import pageobjects.ClientPage;
import pageobjects.HomePage; 
import util.DriverManager;

public class LoginSteps 
{

    public HomePage Login(String nam, String pas) {
        HomePage homePageObj = PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.driver, HomePage.class);
        homePageObj.userLogin(nam,pas);

        return homePageObj;
    }


}
```

**Util:**

```
package util;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DriverManager 
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl="//http:qms";
    public DriverManager()
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/naveen/chromedriver");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

}
```

**Login Test :**

```
 package login;
 import org.testng.Assert;
 import org.testng.annotations.*;
 import pageobjects.HomePage;
 import steps.LoginSteps;
 import util.DriverManager;
 import static util.DriverManager.driver;

 public class loginTest
 {
        @BeforeSuite(groups = {"regression"})
        public void initDriver(){
            DriverManager manager = new DriverManager();
        }


        @DataProvider(name= "login")
        public static java.lang.Object[][] loginData(){

            return new Object[][]{{"geoso","1"},{"ges","2"},{"geo","1"}};
        }
        @Test(dataProvider = "login")
        public void verifyValidLoginWithDataProvider(String userName,String password)
        {
            LoginSteps loginSteps= new LoginSteps();
            HomePage ex=loginSteps.Login(userName,password);
            Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello Naveen"));

        }
    }
```

Here is the scenario of `json format` Please tell me how to write the code?
first open URL and go to login page then .

```
login
{

"username" :"ertte"
password: "34"
}
"Admin"
"users"
"add users"
"username" :"tsrt"
"password":"sdfgsdrfg"
name:"gfgf"
nickname:"fgsdgf"
role:"client"
email:"sdfsd@gmail.com"
submit
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many different frameworks you can use now in combination with selenium.

I use Cucumber [**BDD**].
You can write your scenarios as regular sentences and Gherkin will transfer them in a methods. Sentences can have parameters or list of a parameters.

You have execution control for your test at two, let call it top levels. You can choose which feature file you want to ran.
Second execution filter can be build by using tags. For e.g. @smoketest @regression and so on.

You can use also TestNG. You have .xml file where you can make your setup. Execute particular clases, methods, prioretize test, make test dependencies, skip tests, and have full control over execution.

There are lot more I assume but these two are the most popular.